# Como mexer com <ul>

Tags: html, css

Olá, gostaria de coloca o "Sair" e o "Login | Cadastro" para cima.

[image]

O input file gostaria de deixar apenas um grande botão como esse sem aquela parte que mostra oque foi selecionado.

[image]

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>LuppBox</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo_index.css"/>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#0099FF">
    <ul id="cabecario">
        <li id="logo"><img src="fotos_site/logo.png" width="auto" height="60" /></li>  
        <li id="login_cadastro_css"><a href="sair.php">Sair</a></li>
        <li id="login_cadastro_css"><a href="login_cadastro.php">Login | Cadastro</a></li>         
    </ul>  
    <?
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['login_usuario']) && isset($_SESSION['senha_usuario']))
    {   
        echo "Olá ".$_SESSION['login_usuario'];
        echo "<p><input id=\"upload\" type=\"file\" value=\"UPLOAD\">";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

estilo_index.css

```
@charset "utf-8";

#cabecario
{
    height:60px;
    width:900px;
    background:#0F3;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#logo
{
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:70px;
}

#login_cadastro_css
{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    alignment-adjust:auto;
    margin-left:750px;
}

#cabecario a
{
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#upload
{
    border-radius:10px;
    background:#006;

    width:400px;
}
```

Comment: Não é uma boa ideia deixar a senha do usuário armazenada na sessão (`$_SESSION['senha_usuario']`)...

Comment: Onde eu deveria deixar ??

Comment: Mantenha-a em um banco de dados criptografada. Ao autenticar o usuário, apenas busque e compare. Não a deixe na sessão pois ela pode ser hackeada. Leia mais em http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda, vou arrumar isso, mas sabe como resolver o problema que citei acima ??

Comment: Estou analisando aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há alguns erros de semântica no seu código e id's duplicados. Aconselho dar uma estudada em HTML e CSS. Mas aqui vai um jeito de chegar próximo do que você espera:

HTML - altere a parte do botão para ser exibido com o PHP:

```
<body>
     <div id="cabecalho">
         <div id="logo"><img src="fotos_site/logo.png" width="auto" height="60" /></div>  
         <div class="links">
             <div><a href="sair.php">Sair</a></div>
             <div><a href="login_cadastro.php">Login | Cadastro</a></div>         
         </div>
     </div>

     <!-- altere para exibir com o PHP -->
     <div id="upload-container" class="fileUpload">
         <span>Upload</span>
         <input id="upload" class="upload" type="file" />
     </div>
 </body>
```

E o CSS:

```
 body  {
     background-color: #0099FF;
 }

 #cabecalho
 {
     height:60px;
     width:900px;
     background:#0F3;
     border-radius:3px;
     margin:0 auto;
 }
 #cabecalho .links {
     float: right;
     margin-right: 15px;
 }

 #logo
 {
     list-style:none;
     margin-left:70px;
     float: left;
 }

 #login_cadastro_css
 {
 }

 #cabecalho a
 {
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size: 18px;
     color: #FFF;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 #upload-container {
     border-radius:10px;
     background:#0F3;
     line-height: 40px;
     letter-spacing: 5px;
     font-size: 25px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     width:400px;
 }

 .fileUpload {
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin: 10px;
 }
 .fileUpload input.upload {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-size: 20px;
     cursor: pointer;
     opacity: 0;
     filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso esta muito bagunçado! Pra que usar uma `ul` pra logo e menu? Primeiro entenda pra que serve a `ul` pra saber se é preciso usar nesse contexto!!!!

## A imagem de upload:

```css
#upload{
  background:#006;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
}
#upload input{
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  opacity:0;
  display:block;
  margin-top:-100px;
}
#upload img{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="upload">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4CQt.png">
<input type="file" value="UPLOAD">
</div>
```